# Why does my react electron app running on macOS restart when closed?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, electron-builder

When running my electron application on macOS, when I close the application and reopen it from my taskbar, it restarts the application.  I know it is because it is creating a new window.  I am not quitting the app, macs and windows work differently.  Is there some electron event I can use to prevent this from happening?

```
import { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, dialog, webContents } from 'electron'
import fs from 'node:fs'
import axios from 'axios'

import path from 'node:path'

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'

process.env.DIST = path.join(__dirname, '../dist')
process.env.PUBLIC = app.isPackaged ? process.env.DIST : path.join(process.env.DIST, '../public')


let win: BrowserWindow | null
const VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL = process.env['VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL']



function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    icon: path.join(process.env.PUBLIC || "", 'electron-vite.svg'),
    height: 800,
    width: isDev? 1500 : 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  })


  //Open DevTools if in dev environment
if (isDev) {
  win?.webContents.openDevTools();
}
 
  win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    win?.webContents.send('main-process-message', (new Date).toLocaleString())
  })

  if (VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    win.loadURL(VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL)
  } else {
    win.loadFile(path.join(process.env.DIST || "", 'index.html'))
  }
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

app.on('activate', () => {  
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow(). <--- I THINK THE PROBLEM EXIST HERE
  }
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
})
```